# Чтение двоичных данных

Tags: python, binary

Среди прочих данных есть последовательность `int, double, double, double`

```
struct.unpack('i3d', data[pos:pos + 4 + 3*8])
```

Ошибка

```
*** struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 32
```

Проверяю

```
struct.calcsize('i')
4

struct.calcsize('3d')
24

struct.calcsize('i3d')
32

struct.calcsize('3di')
28
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А длина data[pos:pos + 4 + 3*8] чему у вас равна?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок байт наверно указать забыли, вот он и интерпретирует как хочет

```
>>> calcsize('<i3d')
28
>>> calcsize('<3di')
28
```